# I want to redirect from root path /index.php to index.php?page=terms

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am making changes in .htaccess file to change root path (/) to index.php?page=terms

Redirect /index.php /index.php?page=terms

but it shows error redirect too many times

Comment: Can you post the current state of your .htaccess

Comment: I have only added this line in htaccess file
Redirect /index.php /index.php?page=terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing the name of the index page? For instance, redirecting from `index.php` to `home.php?page=terms`
The page might be redirecting ALL `index.php` pages (including the `index.php?page=terms`) since it is, after all, the same page just with a little bit of GET info in the URL.

Alternatively, you might want to just use something like:

```
    if(!isset($_GET["page"])){
      header("Location: index.php?page=terms");
    }
```

which will redirect if the `?page=` isn't there. This doesn't require any `.htaccess` changes.

Comment: Out of curiosity (and for those who have the same issue in the future), what was the solution that worked for you?